# Output of "System.out.print(0.7*0.7==0.49);"

Tags: java

```
System.out.print(0.7*0.7==0.49);
```

Why does this code outputs false?

I saw this in my practice exam and I have am really confused.

Comment: Because of Floating-Point Arithmetic. Google it.

Comment: How is numbers like 0.7 and 0.49 represented internally?  Consider printing out 0.49 - 0.7*0.7

Comment: Must-read: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: because 0.7 is not actually 0.7 and neighter is 0.49 actually 0.49 internally

Comment: This would be a very peculiar exam that would require students to tell whether `0.7*0.7==0.49` is true or false in Java. The answer is completely determined by the IEEE 754 standard and the Java Language Specification's reliance on the former for floating-point, but converting `0.7` to binary64 by hand is not a useful skill to practice.